# Disabling effect of ViewEncapsulation.None in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular2viewencapsulation

How to disable the effect of ViewEncapsulation.None? 
E.g. One of my component (firstComponent) defines a css class with some properties. There is secondComponent which uses the same css class. 
I want my "secondComponent" to use the different specific values for properties defined by first component stylesheet. How can I achieve this?

Note : I redefined the same class in "secondComponent" with different values, keeping the viewEncapsulation of secondComponent default. It didn't work for me.

```
FirstComponent:
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "FirstComponent",
    templateUrl: 'FirstComponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['FirstComponent.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
FirstComponent.component.css

.ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;
}

Second Component:
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "SecondComponent",
    templateUrl: 'SecondComponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['SecondComponent.component.css'],
})
SecondComponent.Component.css

.ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

I am creating p-tree in both the component, which internally uses .ui-tree-container. I want my secondComponent's tree's background should be white, while for all other places tree's background should remain black.

Comment: show some code maybe

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: attach code and then `Ctrl+K` to show it as code and not as text

Comment: Added code for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate your css within your component selectors.

`FirstComponent.component.css`

```
FirstComponent .ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: white;
}
```

`SecondComponent.component.css`

```
SecondComponent .ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

With this way, they will not affect each other templates. Also, you can choose to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` for both/either of them or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Default ViewEncapsulation for the FirstComponent as well, and instead use ::ng-deep selector in your css files respectively.

SecondComponent

```
::ng-deep .ui-tree .ui-tree-container{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

FirstComponent

```
::ng-deep .ui-tree .ui-tree-container{
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse CSS white only customising somes parts, you could make use of scss variables

**Step #1**

Create a scss file with common properties and default colors

**commontree.scss**

```
$bgColor : white !default;
$color: black !default;

.ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
    background-color: $bgColor;
    color: $color;
}
```

**Step #2**

In your component's scss file, modify the variables' values if needed and import the comon scss file

**component1.scsss**

```
$bgColor:  #252525; /* Override colors */
$color: white;
@import './commontree.scss';
```

**component2.scss**

```
/* Use default colors */
@import './commontree.scss';
```

For this, you can (and probably should) keep view encapsulation to the default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvotjt?file=app%2Fcomponent2.scss)